# E_PARSE errors only showing in New Relic in Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php, newrelic

I have a weird not so helpful error in New Relic. These errors are not showing in Laravel logs OR in raw php logs. For example :

```
Error message
E_PARSE: syntax error, unexpected '\Foundatio', expecting \\ (T_NS_SEPARATOR) or ';' or '{'

Sample stack trace
in require called at /home/xxx/public_html/bootstrap/autoload.php (32)
in require called at /home/xxx/public_html/public/index.php (36)
```

or

```
Error message
E_PARSE: syntax error, unexpected '\Support {', expecting \\ (T_NS_SEPARATOR) or ';' or '{'

Sample stack trace
in require called at /home/xxx/public_html/bootstrap/autoload.php (32)
in require called at /home/xxx/public_html/public/index.php (36)
```

or

```
Error message
E_PARSE: syntax error, unexpected '\Compon', expecting \\ (T_NS_SEPARATOR) or ';' or '{'

Stack trace
in require called at /home/xxx/public_html/bootstrap/autoload.php (32)
in require called at /home/xxx/public_html/public/index.php (36)
```

**These errors seem to happen everytime I run a `composer install` on the server.** The times of my commit/deployment seem to match the time of the errors in New Relic.

Any idea what this can be, and why I don't get them in the logs but they show up in New Relic ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

The errors don't show in Laravel logs because Laravel is not even run. Parse errors are detected when a file is loaded and the file does not get executed.

Comment: Thanks, so do you have any idea why I get these only on composer install ?

Comment: After packages are installed new versions of various files are generated, e.g. compiled.php. I guess if some request comes when the files are not fully generated you might get parse errors

Comment: ah, that makes sense. The site has quite a bit of traffic... I think I have to move to a better deployment process.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jerdrzej I realized I was being a bit reckless.

If anyone has this issue, solution is to use a proper way to deploy your code (the user only gets to see the new code if everything went well with the deployment -- NO DOWNTIME).

I use dploy.io and with their last update (they changed the name to DeployBot) they can do that :

http://deploybot.com/

Or there is Envoyer from the Laravel team :

https://envoyer.io/

There are probably other way to avoid the downtime, but this will work for me.